# canJS: load model with associations, but only save the "base" model

Tags: javascript, jquery, canjs, canjs-model

[Here is a demo](http://jsbin.com/owuvam/1/edit), how to load a model with associations (in a single request) in canJS.
I found it in the [github repo of canJS](https://github.com/bitovi/canjs), [here](https://github.com/bitovi/canjs/blob/master/model/pages/associations.html), and actually I had to rewrite it a little bit to work (it was outdated), but it works now.

My problem is, that if I change a loaded contact (`contact.attr('name', 'Tom');`), and then I want to save it (`contact.save();`), then the contact, and also the contact's tasks will be posted via ajax to the server, to be saved. This is logical, because the `tasks` is an attribute of `contact`.

My problem is, that I only want the contact `name`, `birthday` and `id` to be posted when updating a record. I probably should override the `makeRequest` method, and remove `tasks` before posting to server, but I thinks there should be a more elegant solution.

Hopefully there are some canJS users here, who handled this situation already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was searching for a solution to this very problem myself, and I came up with my own one, inspired by trickey's suggestion on the JavascriptMVC forum in [this post](https://forum.javascriptmvc.com/topic/how-to-wrap-data-sent-to-server) about modifying the `serialize()` model method to make it play more nicely with Rails.

Like his suggestion, I created my own extension of the Model class, and I added an `include` field on my models where you can list the attributes you'd like to include (patterned after the Rails as_json method).

```
can.Model("BaseModel", {}, {
  serialize: function() {
    var data, retval, serialized;
    data = {};
    retval = {};
    serialized = can.Model.prototype.serialize.call(this);
    //check if we're using the "include" fields or not
    if (typeof this.constructor.include !== 'undefined') {
      can.each(this.constructor.include, function(attr) {
        data[attr] = serialized[attr];
      });
    } else {
      data = serialized;
    }
    //wrap the return value in the model name for Rails purposes, e.g. {"event": {data}}
    retval[this.constructor._shortName] = data;
    return retval;
  }
});
```

Then in my model I use the "include" array to indicate which fields I want to include. By omitting "attendees" and "speakers", those associated models will not be packaged into my serialized JSON that gets sent back to the server.

```
Event = BaseModel.extend('Event', {
  findAll: "GET /admin/events",
  findOne: "GET /admin/events/{id}",
  create: "POST /admin/events",
  update: "PUT /admin/events/{id}",
  destroy: "DELETE /admin/events/{id}",
  attributes: {
    attendees: 'Models.User.models',
    speakers: 'Models.User.models'
  },
  include: ['id', 'name', 'start_time', 'end_time']
}, {});
```

Comment: Hey kaptron. Thank you for your answer. This can be a possible workaround, and actually it is an elegant one! :) Thank your for sharing your idea.